# How do I generate an aluminum force-field for a LAMMPS input file?

Tags: molecular-modeling, molecular-dynamics, pseudopotentials, lammps, forcefields

I have been assigned a project on the generation of a force-field of Al (aluminum) for a LAMMPS potential.

I have no idea how to proceed and what to do next. Can anyone please let me know how should I proceed further?

Comment: Welcome to the Matter Modeling! If you haven't yet, take the [tour] and visit the [help]. It may help you get an answer if you clarify what you do know so far. Have you looked for any tutorials on how to generate forcefields? Have you used LAMMPS before? Was this assigned by a research advisor instructor for a course who could get you started?

Comment: This may help you https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1133/24

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: The user has not signed in since 1 day after writing the question, which was 2 weeks ago. It is unlikely that they will answer Tyberius's question or see Camps's suggested link, or my suggested link to the LAMMPS chat room. The question can easily be reopened if the user comes back and answers Tyberius's question or someone comments saying they want to answer :)

Comment: By the way, there is a LAMMPS chat room here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109805/lammps. Please check it out and say hello at least once so that you become a member of the room! (about more 2 weeks have passed and the asker still hasn't signed in since asking the question, but I am hopeful that they will come back :))